# Thawing haggis safely

Tags: food-safety, thawing

I have a large frozen haggis that I'd like to use for dinner Saturday night.  when do i start to thaw it, and whats the safest method of thawing to prevent both food borne illness and to preserve quality of the product?  I already read the question about cooking haggis from frozen, and decided I don't want to do that.

Comment: As Elendil says, it doesn't matter that it's haggis. There is no need to repeat the same instructions for every possible frozen food. Also see http://cooking.stackexchange.com/tags/food-safety/info for a roundup on foood safety.

Answer (score 0):

Defrosting haggis is no different to defrosting any other perishable food. It shouldn't be at room temperature for more than 2 hours. That means:

- Defrosting in the fridge for 24 hours
- Defrosting by running it under cold water for no more than 2 hours, then cooking it straight away.

There really is no problem with cooking haggis from frozen (or after partially defrosting), so long as you ensure it's piping hot throughout when you take it out of the oven. Use a probe thermometer if possible to ensure a safe temperature (75°C is a safe bet).